# Where to find historical hedge fund returns?

Tags: rate-of-return, hedge-funds

Where can I find historical hedge fund return information? Are there any free resources?

Answer (score 2):

This is the beauty of a hedge fund they are not required to release this information. Heck sometimes you can't even pull your money out if the fund manager issues an injunction. The best thing I have ever come up with is to ask questions about their strategy (black swan, etc) and try to distill it out yourself based on statements. Unless you are a VERY experienced financial analyst it will be very hard, and you should brush up on your stochastic calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here are some:

[Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/HFRXGL%3aIND)
[HedgeIndex](http://www.hedgeindex.com/hedgeindex/en/default.aspx?cy=USD)
[BarclayHedge](http://www.barclayhedge.com/research/indices/ghs/Hedge_Fund_Index.html)

Best of luck in your information hunt.